# Async ajax request w/ jQuery freezes Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, request

So I'm doing a pretty basic ajax request, but I can't make it non-blocking in chrome. Is there anything wrong with this request? IE handles it well, but chrome freezes completely for seconds. The timeout event is fired after chrome stops freezing.

```
    setTimeout(this.onExtendedSaveTimeCallback, 1000);

    this.isSaving = true;
    this.request = $.ajax({
        url:      'http://same-origin.com',
        type:     'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data:      data,
        async:     true,
    });

    this.request.done(function(response) {
        self.isSaving = false;
        self.$rootElement.find('.save').removeClass('saving');
        if(response != "SUCCESS")
        {
            // The input did not pass validation
            // Show the error message
            self.$rootElement.find('.edit-mode-content').prepend(response);
            self.$rootElement.find('.error').slideDown(200);
            self.$rootElement.find('.save').html('Spara');
            self.unblockRowInput();
        }
        else
            self.close(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think its the ajax call.  I've seen similar situations, with the browser choking, when creating the ajax data parameter is expensive.  Depending on how you're doing looping/dom traversal, performance can vary a good amount cross browser.  To verify, try submitting the ajax request without doing the work to create the data parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma after `async: true,` ... is that intentional?